# Is it fine to use .obs on Widgets after assing to var?

Tags: flutter-getx

Hey am Wondering is it fine to use ".obs" to widget like this :

```
        var name= Text("foo").obs;
        return name.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

using `.obs` on whole widgets like this:

```
Rx<Widget> textWidget = Text("test").obs;
```

will work fine, as you can try in this exmaple:

```
  // ...
   child: Obx(
        () => controller.textWidget.value,
      ),
```

and every time you assign a `value` to it, it will update, but this will cuase very unecessary recreating of that `Text` widget, since each time, a new `Text` widget will set in your UI, which may cause perferemnce issue.

instead you should declare primitive types as `Rx` observales then assignig them inside your UI widgets:

```
final textVal = "test".ons;

 child: Obx(
      () => Text(controller.textVal.value),
    ),
```